# Check socket writeable with select while read buffer full

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi

I am trying to check whether a socket is writeable before using `send`. This works fine, unless the socket's read-buffer is full, then `select` timeouts (at least that's what i am expecting, the behavior is that after sending a lot of data to the socket without using `recv`, `select` returns 0. If i read something and try again, it behaves normally again). I expect that a full read-buffer would not prevent sending. What am i doing wrong?

```
int testwriteable(SOCKET socket) {
  timeval timeout;
  timeout.tv_sec = 0;
  timeout.tv_usec = 100; //100 us (microseconds)

  fd_set set;
  FD_ZERO(&set);
  FD_SET(socket, &set);

  //check for writable
  return select(1, NULL, &set, NULL, &timeout);
}
```

Comment: Unable to repro (Win 10 64-bit, VS 2015 R3). This entire function strikes me as *perverse* though, you do a lot of work for a single socket, and the value of the information returned is dubious. Presumably you are checking for your function returning SOCKET_ERROR, and you aren't assuming that because the socket is writable it will accept *all* of the data you want to present to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `select()` times out with this code it means the send buffer was full for the entire period of the timeout.

But you're doing this wrong. You should have a main `select()` loop that drives your code, not this inversion of control, and you should (a) just write when you have something to write, (b) detect when it returns -1/EWOULDBLOCK/EAGAIN, and (c) at that point add the socket FD to the `writeFDs` set and defer the write until the socket becomes writable. When that happens, retry the write (which implies that you've queued the data and its length somewhere), and if that succeeds remove the socket FD from `writeFDs`.

Comment: `means the send buffer was full`, to be pedantic, it indicates that a `send`, `sendto` or `WSASendto` would block, which can also be because a non-blocking `connect()` hasn't finished.

Comment: @kfsone Correct. In this case however he knows his read buffer is full, which implies a complete connection.

Comment: I assume the issue comes from the other side blocking on send eventually when the read-buffer is full. Due to the sending part of the other side being a debug test, it sends on the read thread and blocks that, causing the send-buffer to indeed fill eventually until data has been read. Me not being sure on how exactly `select` and other things work then lead to misinterpreting the problem. Thanks for pointing out the proper way to do things, i didn't even know about `ioctlsocket` (on windows) and will read a bit then attempt to rewrite parts of the code. I usually do not write c++/winapi code.